# Windows Phone 7 textbox validation using MVVM light

Tags: validation, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

What is the best way to do this for a WP7 7.0 app (SL3).  Should I use visual states? IS there a way to use attributes from the model sort of like the Silverlight examples would do ? Any good examples with MVVM+WP7?

So far all I can find is these two examples.

http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/simple-textbox-validation-wp7/
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Building-WP7-Custom-Validation-Control---Architecture-amp-Basic-Prototype

Comment: Why the down vote it is a valid question. +1 to level up.

Comment: You can look at my example of WP7 validation if it is still relevant: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/windows-phone-7-validation

Answer (score 0):

For every view you should to make files named Validated(ViewName).cs. Everyone should inherit from ValidatedModelBase implemented interfaces INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifiDataError.

Properties of ValidationModelBase:
IsValid
ShowErrors

Methods:
T ToModel - convert all ValidatedModel fields to ViewModel
void Validate:

```
public void Validate()
    {
        var fields = new List<string>();
        var type = this.GetType();
        var baseType = typeof(ValidatedModelBase<T>);

        while (type != baseType)
        {
            fields.AddRange(type.GetFields()
                .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(String) && field.Name.EndsWith("PropertyName"))
                .Select(field => field.GetValue(this) as String));

            type = type.BaseType;
        }

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            this.SetErrors(field, this.Validate(field), false);
        }

        this.RefreshIsValid();
    }
```

virtual IList Validate(string propertyName) - it will be implemented in ValidatedModels, where You give property name to validate as parameters and handle it in simple switch/case instruction.

I can write more about my method, if You want.

Comment: I don't completely understand. But am I correct that what this dows is use the attibutes of the model to figure out how to validate each field ?

Comment: You always binding fields in Views to ValidatedModel (Binding VaildatedModel.FieldName).

Comment: Ill try my best to understand. If you have any sample code let me know. ValidatedModel = ViewModel ?  I am just trying to figure out how this would be used with WP7/MVVMLight and a simple textbox and submit button .

Comment: You bind user controls to ValidatedModel and then from validated model pass all properties after validation to the ViewModel.